# how does the MySQL get space for database?

Tags: mysql

how does the MySQL get space for database? I want to find out how many records can be inserted into each table of database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL stores content in files, usually inside the normal file system. The maximum file size is only limited by the file system, modern file systems have no limit here you will match. So the answer to your real question is: you can add more records than there are sand corns inside this solar system.

There are exceptions to this, for example special storage engines. But the answer should be correct for typical use cases.